# Google Chrome video timeline and volume bar dragging

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video, html5-video

I am creating a video watching system with the HTML5 video tag. I have one problem and I don't know if the problem is because of my code or of Google Chrome.

Everything works fine until I try to drag the timeline bar or volume bar. Can anybody please help me? The problem is that the moment I click and unclick it does not stop dragging the bar around. So when I drag and leave it, it doesn't stop dragging. I have tried everything like clicking around but the only thing that worked was when I reload the page.

My code:

```
<video controls width="640" height="264" poster=""><source src="uploads/video1.mp4" />To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="html5-video-support.html" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></video>
```

Comment: You are probably missing the `-movflags faststart` option on the MP4 you created. Use `qt-faststart` to fix the file.

Comment: For anyone who ends up here in 2022+ we had a similar issue in Chrome for Mac where dragging the timeline would eventually freeze the video and would never start playing again until after restarting Chrome totally (reload didn't help either). It turned out to be somehow caused by the server since if we moved the video to another server it worked fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Don't think your code is having any issue, It might be because of the type of mp4 file you are using.

Please use following piece of your code working perfectly fine (I have used different mp4 source file)

```
<video controls width="320" height="264" poster="">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" />
   To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser   
   that <a href="html5-video-support.html" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>  
</video>
```

Comment: I have placed same code under this link. http://jsfiddle.net/VA3tC/    On my machine it is working on all browser.